# Check input for UCase (RegEx) and convert in UCase if LCase

Tags: regex, hta

I'm having the following script:

```
Function IsValidLetter( Letter )

const IVNAME_TEST = "[A-Z]{1,2}"
Dim regEx, match, myMatches
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = IVNAME_TEST
regex.IgnoreCase = false

Set myMatches = regEx.Execute( UCase(Letter) )
If myMatches.Count > 0 Then
    IsValidLetter = true
End If
End function
```

It works great, because I want maximum 2 letter from A-Z in an input field. My question; how do I check if the input is lower or uppercase? Best solution would be if it converts it 'on the fly' with this function.

PS: 'Letter' is an input value from a HTML file.

**UPDATE:**

```
Sub SetFullName
    UppercaseConvert.Value = Letter.Value
    CombinedName.Value = Ucase(CombinedName.Value)
End Sub
```

Works great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could have:

1. set `regex.IgnoreCase = true`

or

2. set `IVNAME_TEST = "[A-Za-z]{1,2}"`